# Get list of user logins

Tags: users, craft4

I would like to get a list of every login of a user. I know I can get a certain user with `craft.users()` but as far as I have seen, I get data for `lastLoginDate` only.

Is there a way to get a complete list of all logins? Is this information even stored?

Answer (score 3):

Craft only stores the most recent login date for users (i.e. the `lastLoginDate`). To get a list of all users and their last login date, you could do something like this:

```
{% set users = craft.users.can('accessCp').all() %}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Last login</th>
    </tr>
    {% for user in users %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.lastLoginDate|default ? user.lastLoginDate|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

If you need to retain a more comprehensive *login history*, as opposed to only the most recent login date, you could try [the Audit plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/audit?craft4).